# "use" statements not parsed by phplint

Tags: php, laravel, sublimetext3, phplint

I try to use SublimeLinter-phplint to lint my php files in Sublime Text 3.  The linter is ran, but does not follow the 'use' statements, thus it does not understand my inheritance and raises more errors. For example, here's a controller :

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }

  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    return response()->json([], 200);
  }

}
```

The first error I get is

```
ERROR: unknown type `Controller'
```

followed by

```
ERROR: unknown method App\Http\Controllers\TestController::middleware
```

Which clearly shows that phplint is not able to understand the 'use' statement. What are the steps to resolve this ? Is it a configuration issue or is phplint not able to do that ? (I'm using laravel 5)

Comment: Try putting the extend controller with the path so it becomes class TestController extends App\Http\Controllers\Controller

Comment: Already tried, it does not work. If I also do the same in App\Http\Controllers\Controller.php so it extends Illuminate\Routing\Controller I get the "unknown type 'Illuminate\Routing\Controller'" error.

Comment: It's not a namespace or class issue, but a type issue. The problem must lie in the controller and not the extend.

Comment: You're right, but it seems that the linter is not able to understand what is in vendor/ (is it linked to composer?) If I go in laravel files and try linting them, I get errors like "unknown type \Illuminate\Routing\Router". How to get phplint to understand it needs to look for files in vendor/ ? doesn't it do it automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` this. This might create problem.  The Controller code will be

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }

  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    return response()->json([], 200);
  }

}
```

Comment: Why might this create the problem ? If I remove it, my code won't be able to know what "Controller" represents.